# Automating IBM SPSS Data Collection survey export?

Tags: python, sql-server, spss

I'm so sorry for the vague question here, but I'm hoping an SPSS expert will be able to help me out here. We have some surveys that are done via SPSS, from which we extract data for an internal report. Right now the process is very cumbersome and requires going to the SPSS Data Collection Interviewer Server Administration page and manually exporting data from two different projects (which takes hours at a time!). We then take that data, massage it, and upload it to another database that drives the internal report.

My question is, does anyone out there know how to automate this process? Is there a SQL Server database behind the SPSS data? Where does the .mdd file come in to play? Can my team (who is well-versed in extracting data from various sources) tap into the SQL Server database behind SPSS to get our data? Or do we need some sort of Python script and plugin?

If I'm missing information that would be helpful in answering the question, please let me know. I'm happy to provide it; I just don't know what to provide.

Thanks so much.

Comment: I've never worked with the Data Collection product, but you can use Python extensions to script analyses when working with regular old *.sav files. SPSS has the worst tech support in the world, but have you tried asking them?

Comment: Thanks Automatic. My problem is I know nothing about SPSS and what I need to script on. Yeah we've reached out to them and they had no idea what we were talking about. I'll see if I can get in touch with them again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't as clean as working directly with whatever database is holding the data, but you could do something with an exported data set:

There may or may not be a way for you to write and run an export script from inside your Admin panel or whatever. If not, you could write a simple Python script using Selenium WebDriver which logs into your admin panel and exports all data to a *.sav data file.

Then you can use the Python SPSS extensions to write your analysis scripts. Note that these scripts have to run on a machine that has a copy of SPSS installed.

Once you have your data and analysis results accessible to Python, you should be able to easily write that to your other database.

Comment: Selenium might be a good option if I'm understanding it right. I wouldn't even need to use Python at that point, because I would have the exported CSV file from the Export Data page on the admin page. More specifically though, I'd be curious if I can use a Python script to hit the data directly to pull it into a CSV file (completely bypassing the admin panel), if that makes sense?

Comment: @xboxremote I think that goes back to this million dollar question of whether or not you can interact directly with the data, wherever they're stored. I think only SPSS tech support can tell you that. At a minimum, though, you should be able to easily automate the export of all the data to a format where you actually can script the analyses.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by other contributors, there are a few ways to achieve this. The simplest I can suggest is using the DMS (data management script) and windows scheduler. Ideally you should follow below steps.

Prerequisite: 
1. You should have access to the server running IBM Data collection
2. Basic knowledge of windows task scheduler 
3. Knowledge of DMS scripting

Approach:
1. Create a new DMS script from the template
2. If you want to perform only data extract / transformation, you only need input and output data source
3. In the input data source, create/build the connection string pointing to your survey on IBM Data collection server. Use the data source as SQL
4. In the select query: use "Select * from VDATA" if you want to export all variables
5. Set the output data connection string by selecting the output data format as SPSS (if you want to export it in SPSS)
6. run the script manually and see if the SPSS export is what is expected
7. Create batch file using text editor (save with .bat extension). Add below lines

cd "C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\DataCollection\6\DDL\Scripts\Data Management\DMS"
Call DMSRun YOURDMSFILENAME.dms

Then add a line to copy (using XCOPY) the data / files extracted to the location where you want to further process it.

8. Save the file and open windows scheduler to schedule the execution of this batch file for data extraction.

If you want to do any further processing, you create an mrs or dms file and add to the batch file.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways you can accomplish easing this task and even automate it completely. However, if you are not an IBM SPSS Data Collection expert and don't have access to somebody who is or have the time to become one, I'd suggest getting in touch with some of the consultants who offer services on the platform. Internally IBM doesn't have many skilled SPSS resources available, so they rely heavily on external partners to do services on a lot of their products. This goes for IBM SPSS Data Collection in particular, but is also largely true for SPSS Statistics.

As noted by previous contributors there is an approach using Python for data cleaning, merging and other transformations and then loading that output into your report database. For maintenance reasons I'd probably not suggest this approach. Though you are most likely able to automate the export of data from SPSS Data Collection to a sav file with a simple SPSS Syntax (and an SPSS add-on data component), it is extremely error prone when upgrading either SPSS Statistics or SPSS Data Collection.

From a best practice standpoint, you ought to use the SPSS Data Collection Data Management module. It is very flexible and hardly requires any maintenance on upgrades, because you are working within the same data model framework (e.g. survey metadata, survey versions, labels etc. is handled implicitly) right until you load your transformed data into your reporting database.

Ideally the approach would be to build the mentioned SPSS Data Collection Data Management script and trigger it at the end of each completed interview. In this way your reporting will be close to real-time (you can make it actual real-time by triggering the DM script during the interview using the interview script events - just a FYI).

All scripting on the SPSS Data Collection platform including Data Management scripting is very VB-like, so for most people knowing VB, it is very easy to get started and it is documented very well in the SPSS Data Collection DDL. There you'll also be able to find examples of extracting survey data from SPSS Data Collection surveys (as well as reading and writing data to/from other databases, files etc.). There are also many examples of data manipulation and transformation.

Lastly, to answer your specific questions:

- Yes, there is always an MS SQL Server behind SPSS Data Collection -
  no exceptions. However, generally speaking the data model is way to
  complex to read out data directly from it. If you have a look in it, 
  you'll quickly realize this.
- The MDD file (short for Meta Data Document) is containing all survey meta
  data including data source specifications, version history etc.
  Without it you'll not be able to make anything of the survey data in
  the database, which is the main reason I'd suggest to stay within the
  SPSS Data Collection platform for as large part of your data handling
  as possible. However, it is indeed just a readable XML file.

Note that the SPSS Data Collection Data Management Module requires a separate license and if the scripting needed is large or complex, you'd probably want base professional too, if that's not what you already use for developing the questionnaires and handling the surveys.

Hope that helps.